# Javascript function not working properly. edit

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a registration form for users to fill in their data and submit for registration. If some fields are empty, a user name is unavailable, or if that user's email is already registered, a warning appears below the submit button, halting their process until their errors are corrected.

Below the `email` and `username` input boxes, there is a span id called `emailstatus` and `unamestatus`, respectively. If the email or user name is already registered or unavailable, a message is placed within that span informing the user. However, whether the message is shown or not, even if there is nothing wrong with the user's information, the span id `status` always has the message "Please correct your errors." which can be found in the javascript function `signup()`. Please help.

HTML:

```
<p>Enter personal details</p>
   //cleaned up code
    <input id="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onblur="checkemail()" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"><span id="emailstatus"></span>

<input id="username" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
<span id="unamestatus"></span>

<button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup();" class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block">Create Account</button>
<span style="font-weight:bold;" id="status"></span>
```

Javascript: signup()

```
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var status = _("status");   

if(unamestatus.innerHTML.value != "" || emailstatus.innerHTML.value != ""){
     status.innerHTML = "Please correct your errors.";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "registration.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                    location.href = "registration_success.php";
                } 
            }
        }
        ajax.send("fn="+fn+"&ln="+ln+"&u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }
}
```

Javascript: checkusername()

```
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        //_("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "registration.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
```

Javascript: checkemail()

```
function checkemail(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    if(e != ""){
        //_("emailstatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "registration.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("emailstatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("emailcheck="+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, I'll clean it up some. @HappyCoding

Comment: Im not sure but i dont like check here. unamestatus.innerHTML.value != "" || emailstatus.innerHTML.value != ""...it will always be executed for unamestatus.innerHTML.value like false, null, whatever. it only will skip if your spans actually empty. So i suggest you to clear warning spans after each submit and before validation.

Comment: You're totally right @MykolaBorysyuk. I have added `onfocus="emptyElement('status')"` for every input. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
} else if(unamestatus.innerHTML.value != "" || emailstatus.innerHTML.value != ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Please correct your errors.";
}
```

`innerHTML` does not have a `value` property.  Use,

```
} else if(unamestatus.innerHTML != "" || emailstatus.innerHTML != ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Please correct your errors.";
}
```

instead, however there are much better ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Better ways? What do you have in mind?